# Relay RefetchContainer does not update props

Tags: reactjs, relay

My RefetchContainer issues a query with the same arguments everytime but the props flowing to the refetchcontainer component are not updated.

This post explains why it's necessary to use variables for your fragment when using a RefetchContainers https://github.com/facebook/relay/issues/2244

But is it necessary to pass variables with different values everytimes we call refetch()?
How can i get the new values into my props?

Here is my createRefetchContainer:

```
export default createRefetchContainer(
  DashboardRefetchContainer,
  {
    dashboardData: graphql`
      fragment DashboardRefetchContainer_dashboardData on Query @argumentDefinitions(
        idFund: {type: "String!"},
      )
      {
        ...DashboardTopMetrics_lastIntraDay
        ...DashboardTopMetrics_last12Month
        specsFundByIdFund(idFund: $idFund) {
          lastOne: fundsByIdFund(orderBy: [CREATED_AT_DESC] first:1) {
            nodes {
              ...Risk_expo
              ...Risk_vars
              betaOneYear
              drawdown
              exposureNet
              cash
              turnover
              benchmark
              volatility1Y
              navY
              nbOrders
            }
          }
        }
        specsFundByIdFund(idFund: $idFund) {
          ...Risk_tresh
        }
      }
    `,
    dashboardGraphData: graphql`
    fragment DashboardRefetchContainer_dashboardGraphData on Query @argumentDefinitions(
      idFund: {type: "String!"},
      fundCond: {type: "FundCondition!"},
    ){
      // more items...
      allFunds(first:7 orderBy: [CREATED_AT_DESC] condition: $fundCond) {
        ...LineFragCount_item
        ...LineFragPerc_item
        ...LineFragWatch_item
      }
      todayAssetAllPortfolio: todayAssetAllPortfolio(idFund: $idFund) {
        nodes {
          name
          priceEur
          expoEur
          valueEur
          asset {
            id
            position
            currency
            perc
            underlyingByUnderlying {
              tickerBbg
              perfDay
              perfWtd
              perfYtd
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    `
  },
  graphql`
    query DashboardRefetchContainerRefetchQuery($idFund: String!, $fundCond: FundCondition!) {
      ...DashboardRefetchContainer_dashboardData @arguments(idFund: $idFund)
      ...DashboardRefetchContainer_dashboardGraphData @arguments(idFund: $idFund, fundCond: $fundCond)
    }
  `
)
```

And here the QueryRenderer graphql query:

```
  query DashboardMainChartsQuery($idFund: String!, $fundCond: FundCondition!) {
    ...DashboardRefetchContainer_dashboardData @arguments(idFund: $idFund)
    ...DashboardRefetchContainer_dashboardGraphData @arguments(idFund: $idFund, fundCond: $fundCond)
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Louis, you must pass a `refetchVariables` to refetch. For example, if you have a `loadMore` function, you could have something like this:

```
  _loadMore() {
  // Increments the number of stories being rendered by 10.
  const refetchVariables = fragmentVariables => ({
    first: fragmentVariables.count + 10,
  });
  this.props.relay.refetch(refetchVariables);
}
```